# Matrix for reflection across a given line

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have the equation $y = mx + k$ and I want to reflect vertices with respect to that line. How would I go about finding that matrix? Is there an example of such a matrix anywhere? I've only found an example for $y = mx$.

Comment: Unless $k = 0$ or you are allowed to change your coordinate system, you won't be able to use *just* a matrix. You need a matrix, plus a translation vector.

Answer (score 2):

For a function to be able to be represented by a matrix, it must be linear.  One of the conditions of linearity is that $f(c~ \vec p) = c ~f(\vec p)$ for all real numbers $c$ and all vectors $\vec p$.

Is that true for your reflection across $y=mx+b$?  Consider $\vec p=(0,~ k/2)$ and $c=2$.

If you do want to construct the reflection using matrices, and you indicated that you already know how to reflect around the line $y=mx$ with a matrix $M_m$, just put the pieces together.  Let $\vec K = (0,~ k)$:

$$\vec r = M_m (\vec p - \vec K) + \vec K = M_m  \vec p + \left(\vec K - M_M \vec K\right)$$

Comment: Yes? I don't know what your point is.

Comment: You asked "is there an example of such a matrix".  I respond with "if such a matrix exists, then a condition must hold".  Then I give you a counter example to the condition.